# apt update from kubernetes cluster gives error Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I deployed a kubernetes cluster and tried to test it with a simple bash pod as follows

kubectl run my-shell --rm -i --tty --image ubuntu -- bash

After I got the shell prompt I tried to do an apt-get update and got into following error

```
root@my-shell-796b6f7d5b-274q9:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Appreciate if you can suggest what is wrong. I feel it is a DNS error or something like that . I have added nameserver as 8.8.8.8 inside the shell pod

Comment: Looks as a proxy issue. Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/899009/sudo-apt-update-always-giving-clearsigned-file-isnt-valid-got-nosplit-does

Comment: I checked this before posting. This seem to be issue with DNS resolution . I tried to add nameserver 8.8.8.8 but does not seem to help.

Comment: are you able to use `wget` command inside the machine? It will give you hint if you have problem with dns or internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a proxy or firewall is blocking the connection.

Does the command work on the machine hosting Kubernetes?

If so, then Kubernetes is interfering with http://*.ubuntu.com/

If not, then it is an issue with your current network